# Simple class using php

Tags: php, class, static, protected, extends

hello I'm new to PHP and I need help to understand the basics of PHP class.

I want to have example of a class that uses private public protected and static.
and how do they work..

Thanks in advance.

Oh I forgot how to extends also.
I'm talking about the parent and child something or what..
Thanks again.

Comment: I think you ought to go read a tutorial first and come back when you have an actual question! At the moment you are basically saying "I know nothing about PHP classes and have not made any effort to learn anything". Have a crack and ask specific questions if you don't understand something.

Comment: @adamnfish ouch, we should help the new users understand the types of questions to ask. But I do have to agree about asking specific questions

Comment: @Phill Pafford I think that's exactly what @adamnfish meant. A terse tone doesn't mean the person is not helpful.:)

Comment: @Phill @Zilch apologies for my brusque response, good luck with the tutorials :)

Comment: you should except answers to your questions

Answer (score 6):

- http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.php
- http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.basic.php
- http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_exception.asp

Google has a ton of examples

Answer (score 2):

All you need : http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.php !

Answer (score 2):

http://www.expertrating.com/courseware/PHPcourse/PHP-Classes-Objects-6.asp

Answer (score 1):

Definitely agree with everyone else.  You should read up on the 550 million online PHP manuals including the links provided in other answers.  In the meantime, you get this:

```
class one {
   private $name;
   const ONE = 'ONE';

   // php magic function.  allocate memory for object upon instantiation
   // called with new
   public function __construct($name = null) {
      $this->init($name);
   }

   protected function name() {
      return $this->name;
   }

   // php magic function called when object variable is accessed in a string context
   public function __toString() {
      return __CLASS__ . ': ' . $this->name;
   }

   // static functions can be called without instantiation
   public static function con() {
      echo self::ONE;
   }

   private function init($name) {
      $this->name = $name;
   }
}


// two cannot overwrite method init() -- it is private.
// two has no access to $name.  It is private in one and not visible to two
class two extends one {
   // protected methods can be overwritten
   protected function name() {
      return parent::name();
   }
   // so can public methods
   public function __toString() {
      return __CLASS__ . ': ' . $this->name();
   }
}

// static method call; no instantiation needed
echo one::con() . "\n"; // ONE
// public methods can be called by child class
echo two::con() . "\n"; // ONE
$one = new one('uno');
echo "$one\n"; // one: uno
$two = new two('dos');
echo "$two\n"; // two: dos
$one->name(); // bork! No public access to this method
```